# If the Schwarzschild radius of the universe is bigger than the universe, how come the universe didn't collapse into a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, cosmological-constant, de-sitter-spacetime

According to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174665/how-can-the-schwarzschild-radius-of-the-universe-be-13-7-billion-light-years#174735), the Schwarzschild radius of the universe is about 3 times the radius of the universe. According to the Newtonian theory of gravity, inside any sphere of a given density, the 3 partial derivatives of the gravitational acceleration with respect to position is always the same. I think that once you get to the scale of the cosmic web, the matter doesn't cluster or get more disperse at a larger scale the contribution of gravity to an overall attraction to the center of the universe should be bigger than the contribution of the Cosmological constant to the opposite. Could that mean the cosmological constant is bigger than was previously thought. I don't think so. I think that instead gravitational attraction has no contribution to the acceleration of the expansion of the universe because the universe doesn't follow Newtonian physics. Matter doesn't have a tendency to accelerate towards the center of the universe because its gravitational attraction to all the other galaxies is balanced because the galaxies near the edge of the universe are moving closer to the speed of light so they have a stronger gravitational field.

Comment: Please note my answer that you linked starts: *Firstly we should note that the universe as a whole is not described by the Schwarzschild metric, so the Schwarzschild radius of the universe is a meaningless concept.* See also [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23118/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given that matter cannot escape a black hole, how did the big bang produce the universe we see today?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26435/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are we inside a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23118/)

Comment: The currently preferred cosmologies assume that the universe is homogeneous & isotropic, so it doesn't have a center or an edge.