# Can our universe be a black hole?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, universe

I watched with interest the [NOVA Black Hole Apocalypse](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/space/black-hole-apocalypse.html) which was fun.  They had a secondary list of vids of one was entitled [Four Types of Black Holes](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/space/four-types-black-holes.html).

Now I thought that black holes don't necessarily have to be dense, if they are very large.  The Swartzchild radius is

$$ r_\text{s} = \frac{2 M G}{c^2} $$

so if the mass-to-radius ratio exceeds

$$ \frac{M}{r} > \frac{c^2}{2 G} $$

you gotta black hole.  But it's only a single power of $r$ in the denominator.  This means, assuming a sphere, if the density exceeds

$$ \frac{M}{\tfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3} > \frac{3 c^2}{8 \pi G r^2} $$

you gotta black hole.  With $r^2$ in the denominator, it appears you wouldn't need a lotta density if the radius is large enough.  With

$ \frac{c^2}{2 G} = 6.7332 × 10^{26} \frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}} $

and $ \frac{M}{r} = 4.5455 × 10^{27} \frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}} $

(Numbers come from Wikipedia. This is including non-baryonic matter and energy, all which should have gravitational effect.)  It looks pretty close, but with these numbers the entire mass and energy of the observable Universe is contained in a radius smaller than the Swartzchild radius.  45.455 is bigger than 6.7332.

Couldn't an entire observeable universe be a black hole?  Wouldn't this be a different *"type"*, a **fifth** type of black hole than the four described in the NOVA vid?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23118/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26193/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247168/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are we inside a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23118/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71668/discussion-on-question-by-robert-bristow-johnson-can-our-universe-be-a-black-hol).