# How do we know we are not inside a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, universe, space-expansion

I watched a documentary on monkey flying into black hole and what it would perceive. Entire history of the universe redshifted in all directions, but without any way of knowing it's passed event horizon. Isn't it what we are seeing? In addition, universe is accelerating towards all directions, which would be perfectly explicable if we were inside the black hole which, as I understand, would be in all directions, because our entire future cone would be pointing there.

EDIT: [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23118) is NOT a duplicate as I am discussing a perceived differences, not only plausibility of this actually being true.

Comment: What documentary is it?

Comment: I would not call this a duplicate, as it does not discuss perceived differences