# Black Holes, Gravity, and the Creation

Tags: cosmology, gravity, black-holes, space-expansion, big-bang

As I suppose we all accept, the universe started as an unintuitive singularity—either, "Let there be light," or "The Big Bang". Something from nothing expanded and at luminal speeds (or greater).

I read about this "Planck Epoch": the time from zero to approximately $10^{-43}$ seconds.  When there was no such thing as mass and gravity, a bunch of energy was being massaged for this eventuality but nothing could hold it together. It is still expanding to this day.

**My question is simply this:**

*Could the upper limit of energy that the Black Hole can contain be dependent on how close this energy is before it reaches the levels of the Planck Epoch?*

After it consumed enough matter (energy), the conditions for gravity to work would no longer exist, just like during the Planck epoch. Extreme amount of energy... unbounded now.

The whole universe is the result of a supermassive Black Hole that swallowed enough to produce Planck epoch energies thus disabling gravity (and all fundamental forces).

Simple... like Einstein liked it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are we inside a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23118/)

Comment: StephenG: Some of it is similar but I think the idea that gravity dissolves when the energies get to those of the Plank Epoch is different.  

Mine also implies that after a Big Bang, smaller black holes will begin to form over the eons until one reaches that Plank Epoch state and that explodes again. OH BOY! Nested Black Holes that eat each other until Big Bang mass and BOOM. This idea seems a path of lesser resistance

Comment: Cyclical, almost fractal like everything seems to be out there, and it violates no known laws. I bet easy to predict and test with the way things sit now.  No time reversal though the effect might be indistinguishable. This seems WAY too obvious.

Analogy: H20 solid=>liquid->steam->liquid->ice again "Old Faithful" our Universe? No time machines. Oscillating conditions found in magnets now superconductive in freezing dead space would always provide a global perturbations changing the conditions just as heat melts ice.

Comment: There is NO friction to stop this machine. I'm feeling like I want someone to disprove this. Nothing is that simple. Well, water is. Huh ?

Comment: Several cosmological models--including one, "Conformal Cyclic Cosmology", by a winner of 2020's Nobel Prize in Physics (Roger Penrose)--do not require any beginning for the universe.  The others include Nikodem Poplawski's "Cosmology with torsion", Aguirre and  Gratton's "Steady-state eternal inflation" (which was accepted as compatible with inflation generally, in a footnote of the last--2003's--revision of the Borde-Guth-Vilenkin Theorem), and Aguirre and Deutsch's "State-to-state cosmology".  Preprints of their papers, found by the authors' names, are freely visible on the Arxiv site.