# Modelling a matter dominated universe collapsing into a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, astrophysics, universe

With the FLRW equations we can get solutions for a matter dominated closed universe in which the finale is an ultimate collapse, but this is only in terms of $a$ (the scale factor) and $t$ (time) and some $q_0$ and $\theta$:

$a = {\frac {q_0}{2 q_0 -1 }  } (cosh (\theta) -1) $,       (1)

$t =  {\frac {q_0}{2 q_0 -1 }  } (sinh(\theta) - \theta)$     (2)

where $dt=a d\theta$

Unfortunately, the FLRW does not show that the model should collapse into a black hole. So it only tells you when things might end depending on $q_0$.  So I will appreciate if someone can give me an opinion of whether the following solution is appropriate for a universe that has collapsed into a black hole. Please feel free to rip it apart if necessary. And secondly, how can the final black hole equation be factored into the FLRW solution to get a complete model? Here it goes.

First the energy of the matter is simply:

$E_{m}= M c^2$     (3)

The gravitational potential energy $U$ of the universe is (see http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1035):

$U = - \frac {3 G M^2} {5 R}$ (4)

For a particle away from the event horizon the Newtonian gravity is simply:

$g r^2 = G M $ (5)

where $r$ is the radial coordinate of the observer. 
If I assume that $U = E$ once the universe has completely collapsed then I get,

$Mc^2 =  - \frac {3 G M^2} {5 R}$ (6)

Substituting (5), I get:

$c^2 = - \frac {3 r^2 g}{5R}$  (7)

And finally,

$R = - \frac{3}{5} \frac {r^2 g}{c^2}$ (8)

Now it turns out that the formula for the Schwarzschild radius in Newtonian gravitational fields is remarkably similar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius):

$R_s = 2 \frac {r^2 g} {c^2}$   (9)

The obvious issue here is that I got the constant $-3/5$ instead $2$.  So the real question now is, are these computations correct and there is a reason for the difference? (for example, a supermassive BH Universe is not the same as your conventional BH). Or is it this a completely wrong approach that yields a completely wrong answer? If wrong, what is the right answer? Note that I tried to avoid solutions with $M$ and $G$ because that results in absurd answers such as those arrived in [If the observable universe were compressed into a super massive black hole, how big would it be?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/if-the-universe-were-compressed-into-a-super-massive-black-hole-how-big-would-i)  (i.e., the radius of the BH would turn out larger than the current radius of the Universe, etc, etc).

Comment: http://grwiki.physics.ncsu.edu/wiki/Oppenheimer-Snyder_Collapse

Comment: @jerry-schirmer I must say that is an excellent reference with a great answer since it combines the Friedman equation with the Schwarzchild.  I am however still a bit curious if the approach that I was taking was correct and, if not, why not.

Comment: @jerry-schirmer  Also I am not quite sure how to use the Oppenheimer-Snyder model for calculating total time. The way I read it is that R(0) would be the current radius of the Universe and M would be the total mass. So the final t = ... equation gives imaginary numbers because R(0)/2M is an infinitesimal number and subtracting -1 is just $\sqrt-1$. So given the M and R(0) which is easily estimated and the only two parameters I really need other than t'', I am not sure how to use them.  Some hint would really help.